# Looking for a Graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, finite-automata

I came across this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271538/1-s2.0-S0304397500X05154/1-s2.0-0304397586901428/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIA32UIDOZAjaZ0YoJQnKXioYkTvcIGvTZ7mC0G6ECTwVAiAgZfDc%2FkRSxSiVOLU2KmrUdXLeMwbl3KmTiorTBoBEyir6AwhdEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMQ5ijjAX9GbUNRbBSKtcDuaNVenDFrQAw3q8gzyFn8ML62v0CpMVm1WO0FqGyCzhf98I5YBA0y%2FO%2B5xmB%2B%2BZLNVawi1IcuiEOUgRXjVcEuWwUp4rdI5%2BtMtJvfAu08sIYG83imU6bs%2Bm9%2BTI9k2MNuIzu%2BSvFpwlhL4a3vw%2B7NN1zRnmceHBbAYnsEuYJRhmhe50dllfNFRGiQwX4UJ6Ewgre%2F8kHE%2BOKc5mly7ojccDrfKfD5XafuP2MQZfYpaDobkO1ZILX%2BWFMLHxkVu2OP73Hr4o9CjLjGj6TnqzpaUSvaXDS5h5eRU7gjwHesbeSCZJ3kNn65QiZxZm%2FhlGTULCv3%2BJot%2BsliBX0hjcCOMmT0YC52KuGEitPZ9fTsrP6TThKtJqX7ng5ZxL3PgzyBDd0gab%2FrlVqOoUMpVMCefpaB93EYwX3XwsY2%2BLzSKNwzdakQq8NlGhz9l0dXbsR4ZpO2kwU%2F3epNWOC9vRCFu4MA7kUWp5FOP%2Bysp3T5XYJXNC%2F2dIKl5aDZY7e2KEUSb86L%2BkHqhC8wGtNjOAhVRK40fN2%2FZLeDCsMv2RTcNBnwNpQSqceRmTYFH4UXGiZrnUVT91YevIpImXc8n%2F33Yktgci9%2FOozsX0XaN2c%2FQwliaPKj0RFMOXZ%2BIwGOqYBJb5rlbIqRU%2F3VQxCbv5bzrGM0IVUto0JaZV%2F4IEAtn17Sy%2Fz3eITFU%2FtGUC9M3VZB37Ed9jkp2qC1BuYqh%2BKot7BN5bhkk017viNFfZWcvZ0v9Ct%2Fc3AR8p6%2FXofMo29J6YN9lKZoORg7qQR3PGyjw2LUnA0zPGXNEYHnnxeC2Zzr66wG63EE7Dv5D4asLIP1VpbrSmrU7ZWH%2FPe12HKVy%2FN6RL7dQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211124T131119Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3XVJP7GC%2F20211124%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=04409a26ca3817d9078fbc026f0d7ef079a4629ce12cf70343ad7ab454d2b41e&hash=ddf183fedd7e464c1b42cbc233343bc3a569e92c8f6092ec713ce40132eea628&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0304397586901428&tid=spdf-46d4e43a-f9a0-4358-a6aa-d1d3e9dd6330&sid=3a80681f6549194d5d89fe97e9d0dd56f1c2gxrqb&type=client) written by Marek Chrobak, in which he presents a method to convert non-deterministic finite automata to a deterministic one, i.e. an automata with a cycle and a tail.

My question is: Is there an algorithm in graph-theory that does a similar thing: transform a rooted directed graph to a functional graph (where each node has exactly one out-edge).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You're asking to transform a directed graph into a functional graph, but you don't say what properties the transformed graph must have. Even if you did say what the properties of the transform are, it's not clear how it's related to programming rather than graph theory.

Comment: Hi; thanks for your answer @PaulHankin.

I'm not sure about the properties actually. What I had in mind is a method that, from the root node of a rooted directed graph, performs successive merge operations of the graph vertexes until we reach a graph that has a series of one out-edge nodes followed by a cycle (kind of a rho-shaped graph).

> it's not clear how it's related to programming rather than graph theory

It's not really related to programming, that's why I added the "graph-theory" tag to the post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.